# Training existing ClassifierFunction on new data

Tags: machine-learning

Let's suppose we have a ClassifierFunction generated by Classify on some training set.

Is it possible to train the existing ClassifierFunction by new training set without access to the old training set? If yes, how?

I'm asking because I have set of data that will be updated by new entires many times, and I would like to update by ClassifierFunction as well, instead of learning from beginning.

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128194/1364