# How can I process many image files with Classify?

Tags: machine-learning

[`Classify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Classify.html) in Mathematica is a highly automated machine learning tool. Though it is not good for production purposes, sometimes it can used as a benchmark tool.

Suppose I have many images that can not be fed into memory at once. Is there any way to feed the images into `Classify` for batch processing?

In [`NetTrain`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetTrain.html), [`File`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/File.html) is used in input, but I'm not sure how to do it when using `Classify`.

I have tried something like

```
Classify[
  <|"class1" -> {File[1], File[2], ...}, 
    "class2" -> {File[11], File[12], ....}|>]
```

It crashed Mathematica.

Comment: This is a good candidate for `ActiveClassification`.

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128194/help-reclassify)

Comment: @rcollyer Is the function support out-of-core train?

Comment: @partida I think that's in the plan, but I don't know how far along it is in implementation, yet.